# Only make an HTML link work with a certain amount of clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might be a strange question but I was wondering if, say, I made a button in HTML and I only wanted it to redirect the user to a new page if they clicked it four times instead of one. Is there any way to achieve this?

I cannot provide much code to work with because I simply do not know where to start, google doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, but with jQuery you could do something like:

```js
$('a').click(function(event) {
    let number_of_clicks = $(this).data('clicks') || 0;
    $(this).data('clicks', ++number_of_clicks);
    if (number_of_clicks < 4) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

There is always a vanilla javascript equivalent so you don't need to use jQuery forcefully, but I think it gives the idea. Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** It works, have tested it. You should, of course, use a better selector instead of "all links".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect to another page only after certain umber of clicks then use a function

```
let count = 0    
$('a').click(()=>{
count ++;
if(count==3){
window.open('location.html')
}
})
```